# android/java - can't feed class when creating object within a condition

Tags: java, android, arrays, oop

Inside my Android Activity I have the following class:

```
class Categoria {
    public String nome;
    public String id;
}
```

Inside another class, I have a loop through an array, and in each entry of this array must feed this two Categorias class' properties. But it is returning null since the vars are starting as null in my Categoria class. The loop is as follows:

```
ArrayList<Categoria> categorias = null;
int eventType = parser.getEventType();

while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){

    String name = null;

    switch(eventType){

        case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
            categorias = new ArrayList<Categoria>();
        break;

        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
            name = parser.getName();
            if("categoria".equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
                Categoria catAtual = new Categoria();
            } else if("nome".equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
                catAtual.nome = parser.nextText();
            } else if("id".equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
                catAtual.id = parser.nextText;
            }
        break;

        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
            name = parser.getName();
            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("categoria") && catAtual != null){
                categorias.add(catAtual);
            }
        break;

    }

    eventType = parser.next();

}
```

Looking quickly, I could run this code without further problems, but Eclipse wouldn't let me since he finds and error in two lines. This:

```
catAtual.nome = parser.nextText();
```

And this:

```
catAtual.id = parser.nextText();
```

Showing this error:

> catAtual cannot be resolved to a variable

I believe it's because the object is being created inside one case and is being used inside another case. Is there a workaround wich wouldn't compromise my whole code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your error:

```
 Categoria catAtual = null;// your fix

while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){

switch(eventType){

    case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
        categorias = new ArrayList<Categoria>();
    break;

    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
        name = parser.getName();
        if("categoria".equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
            catAtual = new Categoria();
        } else if("nome".equalsIgnoreCase(name) && catAtual != null){
            catAtual.nome = parser.nextText();
        } else if("id".equalsIgnoreCase(name)  && catAtual != null){
            catAtual.id = parser.nextText;
        }
    break;

    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
        name = parser.getName();
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("categoria") && catAtual != null){
            categorias.add(catAtual);
        }
    break;

}

...
```

Since you use `if`, `else if("nome".equalsIgnoreCase(name))` don't know where you defined `catAtual`.

Start it before `while` loop

BTW, add `&& catAtual != null` validation to both `if` statemants to prevent `NullPointerException`